# nestjs testing - how to start a server with jest mocked modules

Tags: node.js, testing, server, jestjs, nestjs

I already have e2e backend tests running using jest and some mocked modules using fastify and now that when I use app.listen it will be able to receive calls.

My problem:

I would like to start the nestjs server with the mocked jest modules to be able to call it from outside without the jest scope e.g. for vulnerability scanning of the api endpoints. I have some external dependencies that I want to exclude - this is why I would like to use my jest mocked nestjs modules.

if I try to used ts-node an error will be thrown in those mocked modules

**command:**

```
npx ts-node run.ts
```

**file: run.ts**

```js
import { initializeApplication } from './app';

(async () => {
  const app = await initializeApplication();
  app.listen(3005, '0.0.0.0');
})();
```

**error:**

```
jest.fn(
^
ReferenceError: jest is not defined
```

I would like to be able to start the nestjs backend with jest mocked nestjs modules to make external api calls against the backend using fake dependencies.